# logback doesn't work in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I try to use logback in Spring boot with below config,

I tried to sperate the log as two types: system log file and business log file,

but the log only show on Console,

no log file generated, anybody can help on this?

Is there necessary to do some config in spring boot config file?

```
    <configuration>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

        <appender name="ROOT_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>logs/sif-interface-sys.log</file>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

                <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${SYSTEM_NAME}/system.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

                <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">

                    <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-20(%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X{requestId}]) %-5level - %logger{80} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender name="BUSINESS_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

            <file>logs/sif-interface-business.log</file>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

                <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${SYSTEM_NAME}/business.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

                <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">

                    <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
                </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-20(%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%X{requestId}]) %-5level - %logger{80} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="ROOT_APPENDER" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="{project-package}" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="BUSINESS_APPENDER" />
        </logger>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: you have not specified for which package it should use business_appender

Comment: @pvpkiran how to do that?

Comment: <logger name="your.package" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="BUSINESS__APPENDER" />
        </logger>

Comment: @pvpkiran , just tried, it only show on console, no log file generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just work it out.
As I use Spring boot, so it has to set a config like this, these two log files will generated

```
logging.config: classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

BTW, it can also display colorful log with below config:

```
spring.output.enabled: DETECT
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
logger name="business-log"
```

you have to use

```
logger name="your.package.to.log"
```

your.package.to.log - name of the package from your project

Comment: just tried, it only show on console, no log file generated.